# About the experiment for pressure in solids in thermodynamic

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I want to understand something: when someone measure the pressure, temperature and specific volume of a material, I think the pressure is applied in all directions of the material. This can be understandable for liquids and gases because the pressure in a closed container and for instance, you can used a piston to increase the pressure in this system. What about in a solid? the pressure or normal stress applied in this solid doesn't mean that the stress in other directions exists, so what kind of equipment is usually used to measure and control this thermodynamic property (oressure) ? Or is my assumption wrong and is not necessary that all direction of the body to be applied the same pressure?

Answer (score 3):

Solids—unlike fluids—can sustain shear stresses and non-equitriaxial stresses without immediately rearranging to eliminate these loads. (Equitriaxial compressive stress is another name for pressure.)

In solids, therefore, the pressure is generalized as the six-independent-element [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor), from which the pressure or [hydrostatic stress component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_stress) is calculated as negative one-third of the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). Unlike fluids, there is also a [deviatoric component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor).

Internal stresses in solids can be modeled using the boundary conditions and analytical or numerical elasticity solutions. Alternatively, they can be estimated based on surface [strain gauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge), for example, in conjunction with constitutive laws of material behavior, or they can be visualized in some cases via coupling with optical properties:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying @Chemomechanics .So basically hydrostatic stress is used as a way to generalized pressure, and that can be used to make thermodynamic tables? I imagined this doesn't work for anisotropic materials because you need to determined for each direction. What about if a material is applied two set of different stresses such that the hydrostatic stress is the same in both cases, it could produce the same thermodynamic property?

Comment: The material property might depend only on the hydrostatic stress, or it might not. Pick up something nearby and try to shear it. Do its properties change? It's under a constant hydrostatic stress of one atmosphere; you're applying additional (deviatoric) stress. I can think of some properties that would change (internal energy, for instance) and some that wouldn't.